# adding className is not working on a particular field

Tags: javascript, html, css, classname

I have a function that checks if a field is empty. if it is it will assign an error class that paints it red. it works on all the fields of my form but one. 
on that one it just adds the class attribute to the element without any value.

this is my function

```
function validateEmptyPass(pass) {
    var a = $('#password-conf');
    var error = "";
    var fieldName;
    if (a[0].value.length === 0) {
        a[0].className ="errorField"
        error= "password field empty"
    } else {
        a[0].className = '';     
    }
    return error;
```

this is what happens to the element.

```
<input id="password-conf" name="passwordConf" rel="Password Confirmation" placeholder="password confirmation" type="password" maxlength="25" tabindex="5" class="">
```

it just happens to that field do you have any idea why?

thank you so much!

Comment: It appears to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/zcongp6c/

Comment: it just keeps assigning an empty class.

Comment: <input class="" id="password-conf" name="passwordConf" rel="Password Confirmation" placeholder="password confirmation" type="password" maxlength="25" tabindex="5">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The must be something diffrent that is wrong. Maybe your class?
Please show us the CSS Code.

Here is a working Code:

```js
function validateEmptyPass(pass) {
  var a = $('#password-conf');
  var error = "";
  var fieldName;
  if (a[0].value.length === 0) {
    a[0].className = "errorField"
    error = "password field empty"
  } else {
    a[0].className = '';
  }
  return error;
}
```

```css
.errorField {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password-conf" name="passwordConf" rel="Password Confirmation" placeholder="password confirmation" type="password" maxlength="25" tabindex="5" class="">

<input type="button" onclick="validateEmptyPass()" value="validateEmptyPass()" />
```

Comment: it still assigns an empty class.

Comment: @AdrianMojica when you press the button (wich executes the function you want) it will change the class, and notice how the background get red as defined in the class.

Comment: yeah, it seems to be working here, as soon as i add it to my code, the class keeps being added as empty :S will have to debug deeper.

Comment: @AdrianMojica do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use .addClass:

```
a[0].addClass("errorField");
```

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Using native JavaScript:

```
a[0].classList.add("errorField");
```

Comment: and what would that change?

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (!a[0].value) {
        a[0].className ="errorField"
        error= "password field empty"
    } else {
        a[0].className = '';     
    }
```